# Merge XML nodes based on attribute value (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to merge XMLnodes elements based on the value of attribute(id) and generate the result to a list using C#

This is the original XML file:

```
   <profiles>
    <profile id="1" >
          <name>John</name>
          <age>23</age>
          <sex>male</sex>
    </profile >

    <profile id="2" >
          <name>Mark</name>
          <age>60</age>
    </profile >
    <profile id="2" >
          <sex>male</sex>
    </profile >
 </profiles>
```

and I need to work on it as it was:

```
       <profiles>
    <profile id="1" >
          <name>John</name>
          <age>23</age>
          <sex>male</sex>
    </profile >

    <profile id="2" >
          <name>Mark</name>
          <age>60</age>        
          <sex>male</sex>
    </profile >
 </profiles>
```

here is my trial but it returns no thing

```
var employee = from emp in fileDoc.Descendants("profile")
               group emp by (string) emp.Attribute("id")
               into emps 
               select new Data
               {
                    ID =emps.Last().Attribute("id") != null ? emps.Last().Attribute("id").Value: "",
                    ProfileName =emps.Elements("name") != null? emps.Elements("name").Last().Value: "",
                    Sex=emps.Elements("sex") != null? emps.Elements("sex").Last().Value: ""
               };
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Show us your code please

Comment: i'm very beginner to XML, I have no idea

Comment: I suggest you start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx And if you have an attempt that does something but not exactly what you want, then you add your C# code here and we'll help you. But now you are asking us to do your work. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx   `XDocument.Load(String)`

Comment: Okay i did some work but it doesnot work correctly, Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load(fileName)

var newXDoc = new XElement("profiles",
                                xDoc.Descendants("profile")
                                .GroupBy(p => p.Attribute("id").Value)
                                .Select(p => new XElement("profile", 
                                                    new XAttribute(p.First().Attribute("id")), 
                                                    p.Elements())));

string newxml = newXDoc.ToString();
```